# Git - push full copy of repository as branch

Tags: git, version, git-branch

I have a local 'working' copy that I want to "freeze" as full version.
On git (bitbucket) the project is still tracked.

What I want to do is to make a branch of the project on GIT and pull the working copy I have offline without affecting the "main" branch of the project

```
commit3 (main)
     |                               
commit2 (main)          commit-of-my-local-copy (version1)
     |                                    |
commit3 (main) ---(branch for version1)----
     |
commit1 (main)
     |
initial-commit (main)
```

I think I should do a remote branch, but I'm not sure how to "upload" the data not affecting the current developement.

Notes:
My local copy currently is not tracked by git (it was a plain download never connected to the bitbucket).
On the bitbucket the branch `version1` already exists.

Comment: Could you use a tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `version1` branch through BitBucket by branching off `main`, then pull that branch on your local machine.

Once you've got that branch locally, checkout that branch and delete all the files within it. Then just drop your downloaded files into the folder and commit that.

Do you use git through the command line?